# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 17.04 (Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBY)

Tags: bluetooth, 17.04, realtek

I know there were some threads about the ideapad bluetooth already...
But the solution(s) did not work at my end so far.

Bluetooth seems to work (blueman is installed) But it won't find any devices.

Here is the information on my system (according to what was requested in earlier posts):

```
**uname -a**
Linux Desmodus 4.10.0-30-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 31 19:38:17 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**lsb_release -a**
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:        17.04
Codename:       zesty

**lsusb**
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13d3:3494 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:1169 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0535 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

**hciconfig -a**
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 80:A5:89:C6:12:8C  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
        RX bytes:1746 acl:0 sco:0 events:118 errors:0
        TX bytes:3782 acl:0 sco:0 commands:115 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'Desmodus'
        Class: 0x0c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xb
        LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x8723
        Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)

**usb-devices | awk '/13d3/' RS=**
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13d3 ProdID=3494 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek 
S:  Product=Bluetooth Radio 
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

Anyone able to help??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reporting it as a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: This device is not supported yet, but it is quite easy to add it. I can do it next week, if you remind me.

Comment: If you create a bug report instead of `usb-devices` output please add output of `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/13d3/' RS=`. The kernel maintainers ask to give the full output, not a partial by `usb-devices`.

Comment: And also please add output of `lspci -nn | grep Net`

Comment: I did as requested.... Hopefully I did it right (my first bug report)   -->  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1708692

Comment: It is almost OK. But you need to add some more info. Look at the last comment. I will fix it try to fix it next week.

Comment: I did as requested (apport-collect)...needed to tweak python a bit before I got it running.  Anyways...it launched the launchepad...I granted token...but I could not see if it actually worked (how is it indicated that the apport-collect made it...??)   Thanks again!!

Comment: It didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @Pilot6 You indicated that the apport-collect info might not be needed...  nevertheless I see an error message in the terminal-window :   <br/>`olli@Desmodus:~$ apport-collect 1708692  <br/>
dpkg-query: Kein Paket gefunden, das auf linux passt`  <br/>
plus some more track-back file messages...is this worth investigating?

Comment: It is wierd, but not related to the question. You can ask another question. Did you try the kernel from the bug report?

Comment: No, I didn't....I understood that you'd prefer me to wait for the solution which is better for rookies (which makes absolute sense :-) )   And I would not mind waiting for this! You guys are awesome and quick!

Comment: I'll try to find some time and make a dkms tomorrow night.

Answer (score 0):

This device is not supported by Linux kernel yet.

I've sent a patch upstream. As a workaround you can use a DKMS module.

Install it this way:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-lp1708692-dkms_0.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i btusb-lp1708692-dkms_0.1_all.deb
```

This module should work for Ubuntu 17.04 and 16.04 with the 4.10 kernel.